# Android, button sizes on different devices

Tags: android

Whenever I create (for an example) a button, it's size is different on different devices. Even if I leave size as default which is wrap_content. Size depends then on font size I guess. Is it possible to make widgets fit on one screen, and then automatically scale them on other screens? If so, how do I do that?

Anyway, if you guys know some good android apps tutorials, you can post them here. Especially if there's practical programming, not just a theory.

Comment: this is extensively covered in http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All user interfaces in Android should be designed to fit the majority of screens.  They would be fluid in nature, re-sizing themselves to any width / height.

Never use hard-coded pixel values for width / height, and instead rely on "wrap-content" or "dip"/"dp" measure for Views, and "sp" instead of "pt" for fonts.  You're not too specific with your question, so I'm guessing this is what you ran into.

For example, a button that's 150px wide may not look right on a high-density screen.  Using a button of 150dp should allow Android to scale it correctly across any screen and still give you a 150px button regardless of screen density / size.

Keep in mind that 150dp button on an 800 x 480 screen will look larger than the same button on a 1980 x 1080 screen.  You can use "fill_parent" to make the button fit the width (or height) of your container, or use the weight property to distribute Views across your display.

Answer (score 1):

Try using wrap_content, fill_parent or match_parent to specify width and height or any hardcoded values in dp

you can also specify dimens for specific screen size like

```
res/values-xlarge 
<dimen name="widget_min">196dp</dimen> 
res/values-large 
<dimen name="widget_min">144dp</dimen> 
res/values-normal 
<dimen name="widget_min">96dp</dimen> 
res/values-small 
<dimen name="widget_min">72dp</dimen>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is by setting **width** to **dp** and **height** to **wrap content**(or also to dp )

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    />
```

By doing so,it's going to be **100dp** on **every screen** there is(you can use it on images as well)

(And if you want to set relative position use  with margins on either parent or other objects )

Sorry if I got something wrong